Maximum of sequence of random variables divided by $\sqrt{n}$ converges
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of real random variables that have the same distribution and finite variance but are not necessarily independent. I am supposed to show that
$$
\frac{\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \lvert X_i \rvert}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0 \ \text{ in probability}.
$$
I have found a proof for the case in which the $X_n$ are independent here but none for the general case which I am interested in. Thanks in advance for any consideration.

Do you have any more information on the dependence structure, or is this all you get?

@minginator This is all I get.

Starting with a somewhat harsh upper bound: $$P\!\biggl(\frac{\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|X_i|}{\sqrt{n}}> \varepsilon\biggr)
= P\!\biggl(\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|X_i| > \varepsilon\sqrt{n}\biggr)
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(|X_i| > \varepsilon\sqrt{n})\leq nP(|X_1|>\varepsilon \sqrt{n})$$ To show that this probability goes to zero, we need to estimate $P(|X_1| > x)$ for large $x$. In particular, one can show that if $E[X^2]<\infty$, then $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^2P(|X_1|>x)=0. \quad (*)$$ Since $x^2 P(|X_1|>x) \to 0$, we have $P(|X_1|>x)=o(1/x^2)$. Thus,$$n P(|X_1| > \varepsilon \sqrt{n}) = n o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = o(1) \to 0.
$$ Therefore, $$P\left(\frac{\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |X_i|}{\sqrt{n}} > \varepsilon\right) 
\leq n P\left(|X_1| > \varepsilon \sqrt{n}\right) \to 0.$$

$(*)$: If this limit were not zero, there would exist a constant $c > 0$ such that for large $x$, $P(|X| > x) \geq c / x^2$. Then
$$E(X^2) = \int_0^\infty 2t P(|X| > t) \, dt \geq \int_0^\infty 2t \frac{c}{t^2} \, dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{2c}{t} \, dt,$$ which diverges, a contradiction. Hence $x^2 P(|X| > x) \to 0$.

Pretty obvious by a set theoretic inclusion. @user65023
